# Why does Firefox display images in the browser sometimes, and only offer to download them other times?

Tags: firefox

What determines, and can it be changed, when for example, in Firefox, you have some image, and you click on *View image*, and it options for download while sometimes he just displays the image?

I'd like it to display the image every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Content-Type` and/or `Content-Disposition` headers (sent from the webserver) determine whether Firefox "dares" to show a file in-line. You can use firebug or tamperdata extensions to view these headers (or sniff them with wireshark if your source is not https).

You can show files in `<img>` tags inline even if they use a nonsupported content-type...

Comment: I tried, but I?m a little confused. What would need to be done for ff to show those images inline (for example, ones from http://www.imagebam.com/) ?

Comment: Where is the problem? `<img src="http://20.imagebam.com/dl.php?ID=52223127&sec=f55ae9365166a422086dd85c1b35b0cf">` works for me. You cannot link to the image inline because it sets Content-Disposition=attachment. Store the image elsewhere if you need to link to the image inline.

Comment: http://www.imagebam.com/image/4fe4f852252026

for example. I don't understand the part about the inline linking. If I cannot view it inline, then what were we talking about all this time ? I thought the above mentioned extensions allow (through some tempering ) just that.

Comment: they allow you to check what the server operator did wrong (in case you operate the server and cannot link the files inline). If the server operator deliberately prevents you from showing the image inline (besides from <img> tags) you cannot do anyhting about it except host the image elsewhere.